# How to display a picture from library in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to display a picture from library in Ionic project.

I used :

- Ionic 3
- Angular 4
- iOS emulator

In Comopent :

```
    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 100,
        sourceType: PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options)
        .then(imageUri => {
            console.log(imageUri);
            this.selectedPictureUri = imageUri;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

In HTML :

```
<img *ngIf="selectedPictureUri" [src]="selectedPictureUri">
```

The URL obtained is the following :

```
file:///Users/...692F7E7A4086/tmp/cdv_photo_015.jpg
```

In console the following error :

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/...692F7E7A4086/tmp/cdv_photo_015.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the renderer used with your Ionic app. If it's `UIWebView` then to make your example work, you need to use the `Sanitizer` class.

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// ....

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

// ...

this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageUri => {
  this.selectedPictureUri = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageUri);
}).catch(console.error);
```

This is needed because Angular does it's best to protect you from XSS attacks, so you need to tell angular explicitly that you want that image to appear there from the local system.

If you use the newer WKWebView you need to read your paths differently, you can find the details in the [blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/) about it on the Ionic Blog. In short:

```js
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

// instead of 
this.selectedPictureUri = imageUri;
// you need to use
this.selectedPictureUri = normalizeURL(imageUri);
```